# Javascript Regex - How to collect first 2 letters of date

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to figure out the first 2 letters of a date from a string like this:

```
... due Monday ...
```

And assign a number to it (Yes, it matters the number to date). Here's what I've tried:

```
var due_min = homework.input.match(/(?:due|by) (.{2})(?:(?:.+?)?)\b/ig)[0].trim().toLowerCase();
    var day_number;
    switch(due_min){
         case 'su':
             day_number = 0;break;
         case 'mo':
             day_number = 1;break;
         case 'tu':
             day_number = 2;break;
         case 'we':
             day_number = 3;break;
         case 'th':
             day_number = 4;break;
         case 'fr':
             day_number = 5;break;
         case 'sa':
             day_number = 6;break;
         default:
             day_number = moment().day()+1;break;
    }
```

But that doesn't seem to work correctly.

I also need to return tomorrow if the regex doesn't match anything.

Comment: What is `.concat("")` for?

Comment: `.match()` always returns an array of strings, or `null` if there's no match.

Comment: Getting rid of `concat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a array to make it easy

a jsfiddle example... http://jsfiddle.net/accqq3ya/3/

```
var regex = /(?:due|by) (.{2})(?:(?:.+?)?)\b/gi
var days = ["su", "mo", "tu", "we", "th", "fr", "sa"];


function getWeekday(text){

    var day = regex.exec(text);
    if( day && (day = day[1]) ){
         var day = days.indexOf(day.toLowerCase().trim());
         if(~day) return day;        
    }
    return moment().day()+1;

}

var day_number = getWeekday(homework.input.value);
```

Comment: That's pretty awesome

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems:

1. You're using the `g` modifier. This makes `.match()` return an array of all the matches of the regexp. This only contains matches of the entire regexp, not the capture groups.
2. Element `0` of the match result is the match of the entire regexp. You want to get capture group 1, so you should use `[1]`, not `[0]`.

Use this instead:

```
var due_min = homework.input.match(/(?:due|by) (.{2})(?:(?:.+?)?)\b/i)[1].trim().toLowerCase();
```

However, if the input doesn't match the regexp, `.match()` will return `null`, not an array, and trying to access `[1]` will get an error. It would be best to assign the result to another variable, test whether it's not null, then do the rest:

```
var match = homework.input.match(/(?:due|by) (.{2})(?:(?:.+?)?)\b/i);
if (match) {
    var due_min = match[1].trim().toLowerCase();
    ...
} else {
    ...
}
```